# How do I set cumulative values in a mongodb document?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, async-await, mongodb-query

I'd like to set a value by adding another value to itself during an update. So far, I'm attempting to use [updates with aggregation piplines](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) to set a value as an accumulator like this:

```
(async function(){
try{
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
    const client = await MongoClient.connect(url, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });

    const db = await client.db('mydb');

    const myCollection = await db.collection('myCollection');

    await myCollection.createIndex({name:1},{unique:true}).catch(reason => console.error(reason));

    for (let i=0;i<7;i++){

        let docExists = await myCollection.findOne({name : 'test'});

        if (await docExists == null){

            await myCollection.updateOne({name : 'test'},{$set: {name : 'test',cumulativeVal : i}}, function(err, res){if (err) throw err;});
        }
        else {
            await myCollection.updateOne({name : 'test'},{$set: {name : 'test',cumulativeVal : {$add: [$cumulativeVal,i]}}}, function(err, res){if (err) throw err;});
        }
    }
    let result = await myCollection.find({})//.catch(e => { throw e; });;
    console.log('Result: ',await result.toArray());
    client.close();
    }
    catch(err){console.error(err); }


})()
```

In the example I'm expecting the final record to be (I get`[]`):

```
{name: "test", cumulativeVal : 21}
```

I think I'm misapplying the `$add` operation here. Edit (it is in fact not getting to the else statement)...

**Is there a standard way to set cumulative values in a mongodb document?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it:

I needed to change the first `updateOne`with`$set` to `insertOne`:

```
(async function(){
try{
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
    const client = await MongoClient.connect(url, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });

    const db = await client.db('mydb');

    const myCollection = await db.collection('myCollection');

    await myCollection.createIndex({name:1},{unique:true}).catch(res => console.error(res));

    for (let i=0;i<7;i++){

        let docExists = await myCollection.findOne({name : 'test'});
        console.log(await docExists)
        if ( docExists == null){
            console.log("null")
            await myCollection.insertOne({name : 'test',"cumulativeVal" : i}, function(err, res){if (err) throw err;});
        }
        else {
          console.log("i",i)
            await myCollection.updateOne({name : 'test'},[{$set: {"cumulativeVal" : {$add: ["$cumulativeVal",i]}}}], function(err, res){if (err) throw err;});
        }
    }
    let result = await myCollection.find({})//.catch(e => { throw e; });;
    console.log('Result: ',await result.toArray());
    client.close();
    }
    catch(err){console.error(err); }


})()
```

It seems that there could be a more concise way however...